# Best way to replace image url with source

Tags: customization

Due to a mistake the image captions have the wrong href. What would be the best way to replace the href with the image's source:

```
post content [caption id="attachment_4900" align="aligncenter" width="600"]
<a href="wrong_url"><img class="size-full wp-image-4900" src="correct_source" alt="text" /></a>
text[/caption]
```

UPDATE: Here's the code I'm using, but it doesn't give the desired results. Instead the end result is the word `test` which I have no idea where it comes from:

```
function updateposts() {
global $post;
    $fh_import = @fopen( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/file.txt', 'r' );

    if ( $fh_import ) {
        while ( ( $line = fgets( $fh_import ) ) !== false ) {
            $ids = explode( '*', $line );
            array_walk( $ids, 'trim' ); 

$newcontent = preg_replace('/href="(.+?)"(.+?)src="(.+?)"/', 'href="$3"$2src="$3"', $post->post_content);

$newpost = array(
  'ID' => $ids[0],
  'post_content'   => $newcontent
);

wp_update_post( $newpost, $wp_error );
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: I'm talking about a great many images. I need to edit this programatically. Something with post_update I suppose?

Answer (score 0):

In post edit screen, select the image and link button in editor will become active, You can update the link in there.